# CI/CD: How to run the initial setup steps (yum upgrade, deps installation etc). Shoud I use a custom Docker image or not?

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, python-manylinux

I have just started experimenting with CI/CD. I want to create a CI/CD pipeline for my project which builds/tests my application on Linux, MacOS, and Windows. For the Linux part, I need to use a specific Docker container (`quay.io/pypa/manylinux2010_x86_64:latest`). Before starting the build in the container I do the usual setup (e.g., `yum -y upgrade`, install `CMake`, etc). And this is where I am starting to get confused. To my understanding, and after spending sometime Googling, the two most common ways to do that are the following:

1) Build a new Docker container which is based on `quay.io/pypa/manylinux2010_x86_64:latest` but also comes with other dependencies installed. An example `Dockerfile` would be the following:

```
FROM quay.io/pypa/manylinux2010_x86_64:latest

RUN yum -y upgrade \
    yum clean all \
    rm -rf /var/cache/yum \
    git clone https://github.com/Kitware/CMake.git \
    cd CMake \
    git checkout -b build v3.15.3 \
    ./configure \
    make \
    make install \
    cd .. \
    rm -r CMake
```

This container is built once and stored in a repository. Then, every time the CI/CD pipeline runs, it fetches and uses this container.

2) Use the `quay.io/pypa/manylinux2010_x86_64:latest` image in the CI/CD pipeline directly and make the `yum -y upgrade` and `CMake` installation commands part of the CI/CD pipeline scripts. This means that every time the CI/CD pipeline runs, it: (a) fetches the docker image, (b) starts the container, (c) runs `yum` and installs the dependencies.

- Can someone provide me with a list with all the pros, cons, and technical implications of the two approaches? The ones I can think of is that approach (1) spends less time during the CI/CD build, but at the same time, the user has to be responsible for building and hosting the custom Docker image.
- Is any of the two approaches considered a bad practice?
- Given my use-case, could you please help me choose which approach is the right one for me?

FYI: I mostly am interested in the GitLab and GitHub Actions CI/CD services.

Comment: Hello AstrOne thanks for the accept: I dont know how much you already know about GitHub Actions. This video is more of an overview but it shows greatly the power of GitHub Actions: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tl4mbL45PKU  I am also thinking about migrating from Jenkins to GitHub Actions, as I was really impressed by the power and convenience of GitHub Actions. And soon there will be tons of Actions available for everything you can imagine. Just try it out, with just a few mouseclicks you can setup a Demo Workflow. Furthermore soon Github will release their on Repository Service...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would defenitely opt for the 1.)

Option 2.) has in my opinion the disadvanteges, that it

1. takes more CPU (you repeatedly do stuff), more Time, more Bandwith,
2. is more error prone/unreliable (every little network outage of the distributions package repo  would lead to a broken build, or every other problem on this level. And you want to keep your CI/CD piplinne es focused as possible to the build of the software itself. Maybe thats the most important part. If a build fails a big red light should go up in your office. And you do not want this to happen for silly network errors, but only for important code errors!
3. can be more undeterministic, so you might geht a different version of one of the installed packages each time...
4. And in theory, due to security reasons it also makes sense doing a "master" that is verified and secure and use that. Every install (if not verified) might introduce security vulnerabilites...

If you do professional software dev, as you do, you require a Docker/Container Repository anyway to upload your build artifacts, normally packaged as a container. So I would build a "golden plate" "build container" and put that into your repository and use this as base for your builds in your CI/CD pipeline. But if this option is too difficult then start with option 2).

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer! You raised some really good points there. Shall I assume that your answer has two typos at the beginning? I think that when you talk about the disadvantages of Option 1 you mean options 2. Unless I misunderstood your answer. Thanks!

Comment: Hello StrOne, I am sorry, you are so right! I fixed it.